# angular material datepicker appear behind uibModal

Tags: angularjs, datepicker

```
    <input time="false" date="true" mdc-datetime-picker="" type="text" id="date" 
        placeholder="Date" ng-model="date" min-date="minDate" max-date="maxDate" 
        class="modal2">
```

This is for date picker. I wrote it in template.html of uibModal. I've tried with z-index but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<style>
    .md-dialog-container {
        z-index: 1200;
    }
</style>
```

This solves it. I inspect the container `<div>` and found its class.

Answer (score 0):

In your code you are not using material datepicker,

```
  <md-datepicker ng-model="myDate" md-placeholder="Enter date"></md-datepicker>
```

**[DEMO](https://plnkr.co/edit/elZRrPheS6EzE8GUqk1D?p=info)**

Answer (score 0):

the below code works fine.

```
<style>
.md-datepicker-calendar-pane{
            position: absolute !important;
            z-index: 99999 !important;
        }
</style>
```

you can use this style in your html..